# How to keep URL parameters when changing the locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I have this method through which a user can change their locale:

```
# locales_controller.rb

class LocalesController < ApplicationController

  def change_locale
    new_locale = params[:set_locale]
    if new_locale
      session[:locale] = new_locale
      url_hash = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path URI(request.referer).path
      url_hash[:locale] = new_locale
      redirect_to url_hash
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
# routes.rb

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{DEFINED_LANGUAGES.join("|")}/ do

    get 'change_locale', :to => 'locales#change_locale'

    ...

end
```

---

```
# application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || I18n.default_locale
    session[:locale] = I18n.locale
  end

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    http_accept_language.compatible_language_from(DEFINED_LANGUAGES) # => e.g. 'de'
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
# application_helper.rb

def locale_switcher
  form_tag url_for(:controller => 'locales', :action => 'change_locale'), :method => 'get', :id => 'locale_switcher' do
    select_tag 'set_locale', options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when a user selects another locale, all other parameters that were present in the URL at that time, are lost. Is there a way to circumvent that?

Answer (score 3):

Currently your locale switcher posts the desired locale to a new route. That makes it very hard to redirect the user back to the page from where the request was posted and - at the same time - change parts of the URL.

Furthermore, it is not possible to have a form action point to a URL that includes query parameters and have this form send its content via the `get` method. The form `submit` would simply remove all existing query parameters and only add key/value pairs that were defined within the form.

To fix this we need to do two things:

1. Send the form to the current URLs instead of a dedicated locale controller
2. Duplicate all existing query parameters as hidden tags into the form

To avoid sanitized HTML in nested content tags in Rails helpers, I suggest adding a new partial to the app. Note that I inlined the `onchange` JavaScript to remove external dependencies.

```
# in app/views/shared/_locale_switcher.html.erb
<%= form_tag url_for(params), method: 'get' do %>
  <% request.query_parameters.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(key, value) %>
  <% end %>

  <%= select_tag(:new_locale, 
                 options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s), 
                 onchange: 'this.form.submit()') %>
<% end %>
```

You can render the new `locale_switcher` partial into every other view or layout file with this line:

```
<%= render 'shared/locale_switcher' %>
```

Last step: Add a `before_action` method to your `ApplicationContoller` that triggers a redirect if the new and the current locale not match:

```
before_action :check_for_locale_change
before_action :set_locale

def check_for_locale_change
  new_locale = params[:new_locale]

  if new_locale.present? && new_locale != params[:locale]
    redirect_to url_for(params.merge(locale: new_locale, new_locale: nil))
  end
end

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_header || I18n.default_locale
  session[:locale] = I18n.locale
end
```

Comment: What is `set_locale: nil` doing in the `redirect_to` here?  Doesn't appear to be a param anywhere.

Comment: @KelseyHannan Exactly it needs to be `new_locale: nil`. I fixed my answer.